# event handlers javascript

Tags: events, handlers

I have some handlers to resize a box, I want to move the box according to the handle that was selected. What would be the best way of implementing this within the loop

```
for (var j = 0; j < allhand.length; j++) {
    aaa[allhand[j]].style.visibility = 'inherit'; 

    aaa[allhand[j]].onmousedown = function(e) {

        document.onmousemove = function(e) {
            // if bottom handle it's been moved then just inc height

            // if right handle it's been moved then just inc width... ?????

            // etc...
            return false;
        };
        document.onmouseup = function(e) {
            stop = false;
            return false;
        };
        return false;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no quick answer, but in Flex i've had good luck using [Rogue Development's Object Handles](http://www.rogue-development.com/objectHandles.html) .. Maybe get the code, take a look ?